# generalized f-mean/power mean inequalities

Tags: inequality, means, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, geometric-inequalities

I'd like to prove the following inequality (which seems to be true by numerics)

$$
(p-1)\frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \leq \Big(\frac{a^p+b^p}{2}\Big)^{2/p}
$$
for all $a,b\in [0,1]$ and $p\in [1,2]$. I'd eventually like a generalization when I am summing over many numbers and not just $2$, but I'd like to see how to prove this simple case first.

Answer (score 1):

By applying the [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure)  where $\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n} = 1$
$$|x_1 y_1 +x_2y_2| \le (x_1^m +x_2^m)^{\frac{1}{m}} (y_1^m +y_2^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

with $(m,n)=\left(\frac{p}{2},\frac{p}{p-2} \right)$, $(x_1,x_2) = (a^2,b^2)$  and $(y_1,y_2) = (1,1)$, we have

\begin{align}
a^2 +b^2 \le \left((a^2)^{\frac{p}{2}}+(b^2)^{\frac{p}{2}} \right)^{\frac{2}{p}} \left(1+1 \right)^{\frac{p-2}{p}} &\iff a^2 +b^2 \le \left(a^p +b^p\right)^{\frac{2}{p}} 2^{\frac{p-2}{p}} \\
&\iff \frac{a^2 +b^2}{2} \le \left(\frac{a^p +b^p}{2}\right)^{\frac{2}{p}} \tag{*}
\end{align}

And because $\frac{a^2 +b^2}{2} \ge (p-1)\frac{a^2 +b^2}{2} $ for $p \in [1,2]$, then from $(*)$ we can conclude that
$$
(p-1)\frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \leq \Big(\frac{a^p+b^p}{2}\Big)^{2/p}
$$

Comment: That looks pretty, but im a bit troubled by your star inequality. Take a=0.7, b=0.9, p=1.3 then it seems like
$$ 
(0.7^2+0.9^2)/2\leq ((0.7^{1.3}+0.9^{1.3})/2)^{2/1.3}
$$

is false. I think the bug is in the fact that when applying Holder you need to ensure that $m,n\geq 0$, but above for $p\in [1,2]$ this is not the case for $n$. So i'm not sure if the star inequality is true.

Comment: @Annonymous I haven't checked the formula with the values you provided but I agree that here, it seems that I can't apply Holder's inequality because $\frac{p}{p-2} <0$. I'll check with another approach.